# How to stop loading data again while using intent to navigate activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have three activities in my application ... I use an intent to navigate between the activities.
My third activity contains a method that fetch data from a web service.
When I press back button on the 3rd activity I go back to the second activity. But when I again come to 3rd activity from the second activity it starts downloading data again.
Please help me!

I am using handler in my 3rd screen..

Second activity uses following code

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Screen2.this,Screen3.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link: [Android Intents - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html).
Using this tutorial

```
startActivityForResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of savedInstance bundle....

Get more info from

[Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

Answer (score 0):

First finish the second activity moving to the third activity.

From third activity call the second activity